# Dynamically choosing tag in React

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have some React components that use SVG, and can be contained within an SVG or not. Consequently, I'd like to have a simple way of letting them render inside `svg` or `g`, depending on a param, something like:

```
export default class SVGComponent extends React.Component{
  get containerElement() {
    return this.props.inSVG ? 'g' : 'svg';
  }
  render() {
    return(<{containerElement}>
      <text>Extendable component</text>
    </{containerElement}>);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work: you can't use template injection in JSX this way. Is there another way I could approach it? It seems like I might be able to do `React.DOM[containerElement]`, but I gather React does not like mixing React.DOM and JSX, and I don't want to move entirely over to React.DOM syntax just for this one function.

Comment: React.createElement(this.containerElement(), {}, <text>asdasd</text>); something like this could work. It mixes up the concepts of JSX and JS though

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this answer [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react)

It seems you can create a variable with the first letter capitalized and use it like a component like this

```
const CustomTag = `h${this.props.priority}`;
<CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>
```

If `this.props.priority == 3` this will render `<h3>Hello</h3>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
render(){
   var content = <text>Extendable component</text>;
   if(this.props.inSVG){
       return (
           <g>{content}</g>
       );
   }
   else {
       return (
           <svg>{content}</svgg>
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not dynamic. It is choosing a statically defined tag at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
export default class SVGComponent extends React.Component{
  get containerElement() {
    var content = (<text>Extendable component</text>);
    return this.props.inSVG ? (<g>{content}</g>) : (<svg>{content}</svg>);
  }
  render() {
    return({containerElement()});
  }
}
```

But, it really depends on how dynamic the `<text>` is.

If the child elements are very dynamic, you might want to render `this.props.children` and add then as children of the component.