# Dynamic tag name in React JSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to write a React component for HTML heading tags (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc.), where the heading level is specified via a prop.

I tried to do it like this:

```
<h{this.props.level}>Hello</h{this.props.level}>
```

And I expected output like:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

But this is not working.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 580, accepted):

No way to do that in-place, just put it in a variable ([with first letter capitalised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505)):

```
const CustomTag = `h${this.props.level}`;

<CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>
```

Comment: Definitely easier than `React.createClass`, I prefer this way. Thanks.

Comment: @zerkms Do you have any idea how to add attributes to CustomTag? thanks

Comment: @Sabrina `<CustomTag foo="bar">`

Comment: Huh. How does this work? If the variable name is lowercase, it just inserts that as a tag (eg. if it was customtag, I would get <customtag>Hello</customtag>). Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I guess it's because with a capital first letter, [it gets interpreted as a React component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components), and html tag names are also considered valid React components so it works. Seems a little fishy, but I'll take it.

Comment: I would like to mention that, if you are going to use a react class here, dont wrap its name in quotes, Don't do this: `'ClassName'`, instead use as `ClassName`, quite intuitive yet sometime we make this mistake!

Comment: If the component is stored in an object's property, a capital first letter isn't necessary. `var foo = { bar: CustomTag }; return <foo.bar />` works fine.

Comment: This should be in the docs. Choosing Types at Runtime is there but this is a very useful variation on what they currently have.

Comment: @GalAbra https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: As @Ibrahim says, this seems "fishy". Since `CustomTag` is capitalized, per the docs Ibrahim cites, we're technically telling React to render the *component* stored in variable `CustomTag` when write `<CustomTag>`. But `CustomTag` is not a component, it's just a string (with a value like `"h1"`)! So it seems to me like we're doing something technically illegal in this answer, that happens to work in the current version of React but has at least a modest risk of breaking at some point in future. I'd thus favour [using `React.createElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45788598/1709587) instead.

Comment: @zerkms to do it generically you can do something like this: `<CustomTag {...attributes} />`. The exploded object will pass as first-level properties in the functional component, they can be referred to by name at the component level. Using `...(test && {attr: val})` for conditionally adding properties.

Answer (score 178):

If you're using TypeScript, you'll have seen an error like this:

> `Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)`

TypeScript does not know that `CustomTag` is a valid HTML tag name and throws an unhelpful error.

To fix, cast `CustomTag` as `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`!

```js
// var name must start with a capital letter
const CustomTag = `h${this.props.level}` as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
// or to let TypeScript check if the tag is valid
// const CustomTag : keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = `h${this.props.level}`;

<CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>
```

Comment: I'm on TypeScript but casting it gives this error: `Types of property 'crossOrigin' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"" | "anonymous" | "use-credentials" | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"" | "anonymous" | "use-credentials" | undefined'.`

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this. I probably would have spent hours trying to type this if this were not here.

Comment: How can you be able to do this with Flow?

Comment: I think ```const Tag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = `h${level}`;``` would be slightly better because if you now use an invalid tag e.g. `headline${level}` TypeScript will complain. (assuming that `level` is typed correctly as literal type)

Comment: Note that the variable apparently must be PascalCased for this to work. I tried `customTag` and still got the same error, but changing it to `CustomTag` fixed everything. I guess typescript probably assumes lower cased tags must be native html elements and validates them differently

Comment: Error : `<Tallest /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components`

Comment: I get the error `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent` on my`className`, `ref` and a spread operator (i.e.`<CustomTag className={styles.example} ref={ref} {...props}>`).

Comment: It's better to use `ElementType<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>` from react: https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/dynamic-tag-name-props-in-react/

Typical names:
- `as`: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/buttons/#button-props, https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#the-as-prop
- `component`: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#props
- `tagName`: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components/#formattedmessage

Comment: `as const` works too if you restrict level to be 1-6

Comment: Now that JSX namespace is deprecated I recommend: `const CustomTag = \`h${this.props.level}\` as keyof React.JSX.IntrinsicElements;`

Comment: ``const Tag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = `h${level}`;``, I love it! interestingly, it doesn't work when using string concatenation like `"h" + level`.

Answer (score 53):

For completeness, if you want to use a dynamic name, you can also directly call [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) instead of using JSX:

```
React.createElement(`h${this.props.level}`, null, 'Hello')
```

This avoids having to create a new variable or component.

With props:

```
React.createElement(
  `h${this.props.level}`,
  {
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  'Hello'
)
```

---

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as `'div'` or `'span'`), or a React component type (a class or a function).
>
> Code written with JSX will be converted to use `React.createElement()`. You will not typically invoke `React.createElement()` directly if you are using JSX. See [React Without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 26):

All the other answers are working fine but I would add some extra, because by doing this:

1. It is a bit safer. Even if your type-checking is failing you still
   return a proper component.
2. It is more declarative. Anybody by looking at this component can see what it could return.
3. Its is more flexible for example instead of 'h1', 'h2', ... for type of your Heading you can have some other abstract concepts 'sm', 'lg' or 'primary', 'secondary'

The Heading component:

```
import React from 'react';

const elements = {
  h1: 'h1',
  h2: 'h2',
  h3: 'h3',
  h4: 'h4',
  h5: 'h5',
  h6: 'h6',
};

function Heading({ type, children, ...props }) {    
  return React.createElement(
    elements[type] || elements.h1, 
    props, 
    children
  );
}

Heading.defaultProps = {
  type: 'h1',
};

export default Heading;
```

Which you can use it like

```
<Heading type="h1">Some Heading</Heading>
```

or you can have a different abstract concept, for example you can define a size props like:

```
import React from 'react';

const elements = {
  xl: 'h1',
  lg: 'h2',
  rg: 'h3',
  sm: 'h4',
  xs: 'h5',
  xxs: 'h6',
};

function Heading({ size, children }) {
  return React.createElement(
    elements[size] || elements.rg, 
    props, 
    children
  );
}

Heading.defaultProps = {
  size: 'rg',
};

export default Heading;
```

Which you can use it like

```
<Heading size="sm">Some Heading</Heading>
```

Comment: Great work here, this is a nice and safe way to do this when using user-provided values.

Answer (score 12):

In the instance of dynamic headings **(h1, h2...)**, a component could return `React.createElement` (mentioned above by [Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45788598/999248)) like so.

```js
const Heading = ({level, children, ...props}) => {
    return React.createElement('h'.concat(level), props , children)
}
```

For composability, both props and children are passed.

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/robstarbuck/g9hbdqne/39/)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I set it up for my project.

> TypographyType.ts

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

export type TagType = 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'p' | 'span';

export type HeadingType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>;
export type ParagraphType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>;
export type SpanType = HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>;

export type TypographyProps = (HeadingType | ParagraphType | SpanType) & {
  variant?:
    | 'h1'
    | 'h2'
    | 'h3'
    | 'h4'
    | 'h5'
    | 'h6'
    | 'body1'
    | 'body2'
    | 'subtitle1'
    | 'subtitle2'
    | 'caption'
    | 'overline'
    | 'button';
};
```

> Typography.tsx

```
    import { FC } from 'react';
    import cn from 'classnames';
    import { typography } from '@/theme';
    
    import { TagType, TypographyProps } from './TypographyType';
    
    const headings = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];
    const paragraphs = ['body1', 'body2', 'subtitle1', 'subtitle2'];
    const spans = ['button', 'caption', 'overline'];
    
    const Typography: FC<TypographyProps> = ({
      children,
      variant = 'body1',
      className,
      ...props
    }) => {
      const { variants } = typography;
    
      const Tag = cn({
        [`${variant}`]: headings.includes(variant),
        [`p`]: paragraphs.includes(variant),
        [`span`]: spans.includes(variant)
      }) as TagType;
    
      return (
        <Tag
          {...props}
          className={cn(
            {
              [`${variants[variant]}`]: variant,
            },
            className
          )}
        >
          {children}
        </Tag>
      );
    };
    
    export default Typography;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give this a try. I implement like this.

```
import { memo, ReactNode } from "react";
import cx from "classnames";

import classes from "./Title.module.scss";

export interface TitleProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  text?: string;
  variant: Sizes;
}

type Sizes = "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
const Title = ({
  className,
  variant = "h1",
  text,
  children,
}: TitleProps): JSX.Element => {
  const Tag = `${variant}` as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
  return (
    <Tag
      className={cx(`${classes.title} ${classes[variant]}`, {
        [`${className}`]: className,
      })}
    >
      {text || children}
    </Tag>
  );
};

export default memo(Title);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//for Typescript
interface ComponentProps {
    containerTag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
}

export const Component = ({ containerTag: CustomTag }: ComponentProps) => {
    return <CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generalising [robstarbuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866429/5506730) you can create a completely dynamic tag component like this:

```
const Tag = ({ tagName, children, ...props }) => (
  React.createElement(tagName, props , children)
)
```

which you can use like:

```
const App = ({ myTagName = 'h1' }) => {
  return (
    <Tag tagName={myTagName} className="foo">
     Hello Tag!
    </Tag>
  )
}
```