# dynamic tag name from string in JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a page with all the icons from `react-material-ui`. I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33471928/763962) but it does not work for me.

I can create the tag alright but it gets converted to all lowercase.

This is my render function

```
render: function () {
   return (
      <AppCanvas>
         <AppBar title="Crowd Invest"
                iconElementLeft={<IconButton> <MUI.Libs.SvgIcons.ActionAccessibility/> </IconButton>}/>

         <div style={{padding: '80px',}}>
            {this.allIcons()}
         </div>
      </AppCanvas>
   );
}
```

This is the `allIcons` function which returns the list

```
  allIcons(){
     let iconsList = [];
     var icon = iconName => {
        const MyIcon = 'MUI.Libs.SvgIcons.' + (JSON.stringify(iconName)).replace(/\"/g, '');
        const key = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf();
        return <MyIcon key={key} name={MyIcon}/>
     }
     for( let iconName in MUI.Libs.SvgIcons) {
        iconsList.push(icon(iconName));
     }
     return iconsList;
  }
```

All the icons are rendered but the tags are all lowercase. This is one of the entries:

```
<mui.libs.svgicons.actionaccessibility 
    name="MUI.Libs.SvgIcons.ActionAccessibility" 
    data-reactid=".0.$=11.$7615d95988e7d7f1098cd4f1">
</mui.libs.svgicons.actionaccessibility>
```

This does obviously not work. What do I need to change to make it render?

Comment: This needs more up-votes. Apparently react only renders html tags in small case. If you don't need react key, a dirty way would be to use `dangerouslysetinnerhtml`.