# React dynamically set custom tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, draftjs

Rather than having to create a component per custom header type, I would like to do so dynamically.

```
const HEADERS = {
   'header-one': 'h1',
   'header-two': 'h2',
   'header-three': 'h3',
   'header-four': 'h4',
   'header-five': 'h5',
};
```

_

```
let tag = HEADERS[type] || 'span';
return (
  <{tag} id={id}>
      {props.children}
  </{tag}>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok after reading this: [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react/33471928#33471928)

I was able to figure it out that it needs to be a capital (NFI why?)

```
const Tag = HEADERS[type] || 'span';
return (
    <Tag id={id}>
        {props.children}
    </Tag>
);
```

Is now working. Still open to better answers or an explanation as too why it needs to be capital..