# Dynamically rendered Tag is always lowercase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to output some svgs and output them from a list, here is my render method:

```
render() {

        const renderTag = () => {
            const Tag = this.props.id
            return(<Tag />)
        } 

        return (
            <div key={this.props.name} className="social-box">
                <a className={this.props.id + "-link"}> 
                    {renderTag()}
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

However, the DOM node is always lowercase i.e. `<facebook>` rather than `<Facebook>` `this.props.id` is correctly rendered to the console as `Facebook`. Can anyone tell me why react or the browser incorrectly renders as lowercase, and therefore not the component, and how to fix?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with your code accept that you are declaring a function in render which will be recreated each time render is called. Can you produce a reproducible demo of your problem

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri there is nothing wrong in doing that, how would that cause this issue? In fact see my answer, which is most probably the cause for this.

Comment: @SamPettersson, when did I say that moving `renderTag` outside of `render` will solve the problem. I just asked the other person to provide a reproducible demo of his problem because even though React converts tags into lower case, the OP problem is that the component is not being rendered

Answer (score 3):

It's a technical implementation of React, all tags get lowercased on this line [here](https://github.com/jisaacks/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/shared/ReactDOMComponent.js#L441), AFAIK it's not possible to render non-lowercased tags and that is by design.

Read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/4188).

Comment: That certainly answers why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that you would take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9) about dynamic components.

The most relevant example from the article:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FooComponent from './foo-component';
import BarComponent from './bar-component';
class MyComponent extends Component {
    components = {
        foo: FooComponent,
        bar: BarComponent
    };
    render() {
       const TagName = this.components[this.props.tag || 'foo'];
       return <TagName />
    }
}
export default MyComponent;
```

you most likely have a limited amount of components that could be rendered, so you might create a dictionary that contain a key (name of the component) to the component itself (as shown in the example) and just use it that way:

```
import Facebook from './FaceBook';
import Twitter from './Twitter';

const components = {
   facebook: Facebook,
   twitter: Twitter
};
    render() {
            return <div key={this.props.name} className="social-box">
                    <a className={this.props.id + "-link"}> 
                        <components[this.props.id] />
                    </a>                
</div>;

    }
```

Comment: I found this article before coming here as a last resort. I implemented this kind of approach, but it, and your code here didn't work.

Comment: i created a test online app for this case:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fwfeez

work as described above

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer eventually. @TomMendelson almost had the answer, but it needed fleshing out a bit more.

A function to create the component outside of the render method, suggested by @ShubhamKhatri actually did the job. Here's the final code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Facebook from './svg/Facebook';
import LinkedIn from './svg/LinkedIn';
import Twitter from './svg/Twitter';
import Pinterest from './svg/Pinterest';

class SocialMediaBox extends React.Component {

    renderElement(item) {
        const Components = {
            'Facebook': Facebook,
            'Twitter': Twitter,
            'Pinterest': Pinterest,
            'LinkedIn': LinkedIn 
        }
        return React.createElement(Components[item], item);
    }

    render() {

        const Element = this.renderElement(this.props.id)

        return 
        (
            <div>
                {Element}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SocialMediaBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question and answers; alongside the answers given in [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react) they helped me to find a solution in my context (making a functional component in Gatsby with [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/) installed):

```js
import React from "react"
import FirstIcon from "../svgs/first-icon.inline.svg"
import SecondIcon from "../svgs/second-icon.inline.svg"
import ThirdIcon from "../svgs/third-icon.inline.svg"

const MyComponent = () => {
  const sections = [
    { heading: "First Section", icon: () => <FirstIcon /> },
    { heading: "Second Section", icon: () => <SecondIcon /> },
    { heading: "Third Section", icon: () => <ThirdIcon /> },
  ]

  return (
    <>
      {sections.map((item, index) => {
        const Icon = item.icon
        return (
          <section key={index}>
            <Icon />
            <h2>{item.heading}</h2>
          </section>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

As mine is a Gatsby project I used the above mentioned plugin, but it itself process svgs with [`svg-react-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-react-loader) so the basic principle should work in any React project using this package.