# ReactJS rendering components based on user select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

So I'm basically a week old to react and have not written any javascript code for years. So please forgive my ignorance if any.

**Question**
I have created three different component classes

```
 const CreatedDate = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'CreatedDate',
  propTypes: {
    name: 'CreateDate',
    from: React.PropTypes.string,
    to: React.PropTypes.string,
    format: React.PropTypes.string,
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
  },
```

//rest of the code and functions

And likewise, I have a class similar to this called ClientSignedDate and 
VerificationDate all of which containing basically same input props but get data from different columns of the same table.

In a separate ParentClass called Filter
I have created an array of these components inside this class

const dateOptions = [CreatedDate,ClientSignedDate,VerificationDate];

It was previously working when there was only one component

```
          <CreatedDate
            from={this.props.filter.createdDateFrom}
            to={this.props.filter.createdDateTo}
            onChange={this.handleCreatedDateChange}
          />
```

And I basically want to render the component based on user selection but I'm not able to figure out how to do so. Something similar to the snippet below but which allows rendering.

```
 <select>{dateOptions.map(x => <option>{x}</option>)}</select>
```

Comment: Are you essentially asking how to render dynamic components, instead of using only static JSX? That's how I understand your question.

Comment: I want to render different components that take in same props based on what the user has selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And I basically want to render the component based on user selection

The simplest way is

```
{ this.state.selection === 1 && <CreatedDate ... /> }
{ this.state.selection === 2 && <ClientSignedDate ... /> }
```

And so on.

Edit: based on additional info, another option is:

```
const dateOptions = [CreatedDate, ClientSignedDate, VerificationDate];
const Comp = dateOptions[this.state.selection];  // pick element
```

then use

```
<Comp 
    from={this.props.filter.createdDateFrom}
    to={this.props.filter.createdDateTo}
    onChange={this.handleCreatedDateChange}
/>
```

Comment: Somebody is down voting all the answers here without any feedback. Thanks for your input I have not had chance to look at this.

Comment: Thanks Man. I was able to go through your code. This is really neat.

Comment: I actually downvoted the other two because they didn't understand what you were asking and thus gave useless answers. Mine was downvoted by someone who didn't understand it either, apparently. Since you told hsz about his solution working perfectly, I'm left wondering why on earth you're putting a Component with functions and properties and stuff inside an `<option>` element. I interpreted your example code as an example of dynamic rendering in general and assumed this isn't actually about `<option>` content at all. Am I wrong after all?

Answer (score 1):

User defined components must be capitalized to be able to render them.

Just try with:

```
<select>{dateOptions.map(Option => <option><Option /></option>)}</select>
```

Also keep in mind to set the `key` property for `option` element.

Comment: Somebody is down voting all the answers here without any feedback. Thanks for your input I have not had chance to look at this.

Comment: @shashwatZing No worries.

Answer (score 1):

React components must be uppercase. From there you can use a variable component.

I recently referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react) which helped me out. It's not exactly what you're asking, but it is stemming from the same problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name) as well.

```
<select>{dateOptions.map((Option, index) => <option key={`unique_${index}`}><Option /></option>)}</select>
```

Make sure your `key` is unique when you use `Array.map`. If you add/remove `Option` components dynamically, you can run into problems using a simple array index in certain situations. Read more about that [here](https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd#d782).

Comment: Somebody is down voting all the answers here without any feedback. Thanks for your input I have not had chance to look at this.

Comment: Haha no worries. If you end up using this let me know if you run into any problems.