# Dynamic rendering of react elements

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of components

```
[
  {
    componentName: 'FieldHeader',
    props: {title:'bla bla},
    showOnDate: '01/01/2019'
  },
  {
    componentName: 'RadioButton',
    props: {},
    showOnDate: '01/01/2018'
  }
]
```

And I am trying to dynamically create elements from this array.

I have an array that has all the components in it.

I am figuring something like:

```
for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        <components[objects[i].componentName] {...props}>
}
```

but doing something like:

```
<components['FieldHeader'] {...props}>
```

throws a compile error.

Is there a way to dynamically render react elements like this?

Comment: how does the `components` object look like? is it just a map of component names or components ?

Comment: @Dhiraj I'm guessing it looks like what's shown under the text "I have an array of components". Which is inaccurate, but I think we know what he means.

Comment: @DaveNewton completely understand. I figured its just better to proceed once all the inaccurate statements are fully answered. Better use of everybody's time I believe.

Comment: @Dhiraj It's perfectly clear what the OP meant.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate components using the string class name.

Instead try this:

```
const components = [
  {
    component: <FieldHeader {...props} >,
    props: {title:'bla bla},
    showOnDate: '01/01/2019'
  },
  {
    component: <RadioButton {...props} >,
    props: {},
    showOnDate: '01/01/2018'
  }
];

return components.map((c) => c.component);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean array of components, check this out:

Try using `.map()` or `.forEach()`. And don't forget to return your component.

Import your components, example:
`import FieldHeader from './components'`

Now define an array, and check that componentName is not a string, but the imported component.

```
// your components array
var myArr = [
    {
        componentName: FieldHeader,
        props: {title:'bla bla},
        showOnDate: '01/01/2019'
    },
    {
        componentName: RadioButton,
        props: {},
        showOnDate: '01/01/2018'
    }
  ]
```

Now, in the render function:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {
                myArr.map((obj, i) => {
                    var ComponentName = obj.componentName;
                    return <ComponentName props={obj.props} />
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Although, obviously this can be simplified into less code, but I've kept it according to the format in your question, to make it easier.
Hope that works!