# React component with dynamic h1, h2, h3 etc tags

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a react component like this. I want this h1 tag to be dynamic. I tried to set it as a prop, but it didnt work. How can I make this h1 tag dynamic, so that, when we use this component, we can set it as a h1, h2, h3 etc.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Text = props => {
   const { className, text } = props;

   return (
      <h1 className={className}>
         {text}
      </h1>
   );
} 

Text.propTypes = { 
   className: PropTypes.string,
   text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Text;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react)

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer. Here it is.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Header = props => {
   const { Tag, className, text } = props;

   return (
      <Tag className={className}>
         {text}
      </Tag>
   );
}

Header.propTypes = {
   Tag: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   className: PropTypes.string,
   text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: props first letter should be small

Answer (score 0):

For the H Tags this is the type `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>`