# Dynamic tag name in jsx and React doesn't pass props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following on [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react)
I tried both suggested answer but both of them seems to not pass any props!!
(Here is a an example of this issue)[https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-torvalds-x7hcv?fontsize=14]
What am i doing wrong?
Here is another example which is not minimal like the one above, using `React.createElement`, which also doesn't work as it should and it seems its not passing any props

```
outputElement = React.createElement(
  `${this.props.UI_Element.type}`,
  {
    ...globalRequiredProperties,
    ...this.props.UI_Element.config
  },
  ...UIChildren
)
```

In short my final goal is creating an imported component, dynamically only by having its type (or name you might say).
**Update 01:**
After constatnly looking i found an alternative way, this uses an array in which you map an string to the actuall component and then create a tag which uses the map to call the component
[**Here is an example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-rgb-w6500?fontsize=14)
This seems to be working as it should but i still would like to avoid creating the map manually, meaning i still wish to only create the component only using `string`!, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are expecting. The demo seems to work as I'd expect.

Comment: « Warning: The tag <MyComponent> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter. » Is `this.props.UI_Element.type` capitalized?

Comment: The demo consists of two parts, first is a normal calling of the component `MyComponent`, and the second is creating a tag which should call this component, and it clearly doesn't work, i think you didn't take a good look at the `render ()`

Comment: @hugo Yes, Of course it is.

Comment: @hugo, In short, i am trying to create a imported component dynamically, i tried both casing but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to not only dynamicly import a component but also create it dynamicly, but this could not be achieve how a dynamic tag was created, after looking for a while i came across a library which exatcly does this!!
The Library is called [react-loadable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable)
[**Here is an example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-poitras-b251h?fontsize=14)
As you can see both the import, the component tag and everything else is created dynamicly just as i want it, hope this helps everyone else too.

Comment: Good! I understand now that in your first example, the tag was created, but it was not really an instance of your component, even though it had the same name.