# React element name as a string variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While skimming through source code of one of the React UI libraries, I've come across this code pattern (I simplify):

```
function Test() {
  let Button = "button";
  // ...
  return <Button>Click me</Button>;
}
```

What's going on here - why does this work?:)

Comment: Similar, however, not quite the same nor as clear questions: [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react), [React / JSX Dynamic Component Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875869/react-jsx-dynamic-component-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSX above is interpreted by React as:

```
function Test() {
  let Button = "button";
  return React.createElement(
    Button,
    null,
    "Click me"
  );
}
```

`Button` is just a `string` variable, set to `"button"`, that gets passed to [`React.createElement(...)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement).