# Can we use a state property as a component in map method?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render the component in the map method by using a state value from db

example: -

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

     <>
        {post.map((ce) => (
          <div key={ce._id}>
            <h2>{ce.tittle}</h2>
            <p>{ce.content}</p>
            <{ce.component}/>   /// i don't no it's right or wrong.
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
```

Comment: What is `ce.component`?  Is it an actual React component?  Is it just a string?  Something else?  This doesn't seem to have anything to do with state and everything to do with what you're trying to render and what data you have to specify it.  Can you update your example to reflect this?

Comment: I just want to add a different - different component on the frontend by using data base value  for eg :-   i import  a header component in my code and i want to show it on frontend by db

Comment: I assume that you're dynamically specifying what component is held in that property. There's probably a better way to conditionally include your component. You might expand the scope of your post to avoid an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic tag name in jsx and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, i think it can be done. But [according to *React*](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime), it has to have a uppercase letter.

```
     <>
        {post.map((ce) => {
          const Comp = ce.component
          return (
            <div key={ce._id}>
              <Comp /> 
            </div>
          )
        ))}
      </>
```

What's inside `ce.component` is important. What's supported, according to doc is a function component such as the following.

```
  const Comp = () => <div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: its not working showing Unexpected token error

Comment: as i said, maybe `Comp` has to be a function, check the _React_ example, you should get that working first before trying your version :)