# Is it possible to dynamically render elements with props using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've been digging around SO and the web at large for a solution, but I can't seem to nail it.

I have two components, `Link` and `Button`. Long story short: they are wrappers for `<a>` and `<button>` elements, but with the added options such as chevrons on the right-side, icons on the left-side, full-width mode, etc.

Here is what I have so far (and [here's the code running on typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgDUUpgUA7eAXgLBZGer44AHwIBnJGghsAJgKGj8MJLFZRBFcsA4rM6egGFcIaQAUcYMXADe5OHABuzVhwD8ALkbP2MCvbEAFhAA7gYBSA44bB5wAEYQEAA2qGwUAPRp9nDAUtGeAJK5ACJImNrAMMDSfnCYAK6JiQDqwDIwATHxSSk1YvyNnQnJ7BQAvpTaylB6aPQAMtoA1gDybInU5hCWcEgAHsqyVsjoMAB0AIJsaEFQABIAKgCyc+cwMCyxdcpiADwPz5drtAAKLJEBIDgAPhsdjgASImE8Yne2gA5mMJjppvo4AAhL4waSrdabSywvYHGRHYhnfFvaT-F5vD5fJC-Rl0wlsUFIcFQmH2aQGRI5RaeY4YU6PCB1CTAhwQmC3dgyZJQP5POac6Q8vkwSEY8h7SCwOA0OhwBZsRakqzcIwgExsW1wABklqWxI2FjEFGN0Hg5vo2udPrg9uMZjD7pDXttmnqV0q0mybAqIYAFLwtmJPCGXaIrTafQBKAVwDJwGQQNlwMS4ejIuqYTBwYIVAJwbPbQlwNAoRJoBooZRm8JwFiogLwNCJFBiCRiU6wytEGB1KBptiouAAKzq1tq0DHwCsexQ4GSsLXG7YNj7c4XbM8AHJ99aALSz+eLl9wUaGv6pq5MiHqHtwWY+p4Ra2mWnDQrY9ggfAiFZNcwCJDIRBsAANLC-hBKE4SRNIeFZBWmQ5KR+G1A0zStO0ZFZE4LA+Ex-j9Ik7EPj+AByF5INxpzCUQyKwqM4Zdj6NTIfe35PlYEncOUMCZt2YgljUN6bnAGY0T8KA8Qu-Hgpw1jyYuEnWMJpyiTAoyQjR9g-EYOgcDsYKKpw+AoEI1nCepElpI55E-GkKAhXAmnkABlBATO0igSGkmQTmeYElGOZwQhsKyahSEBBhWEQtxgQhGEERRNxlZUbhNH1I0LRtAE3EsS4MClZx3EWSZgk0TZdniZJ6kyYlKFGYu-6SSpamllpSDrjpemhZ89J3j1AlmRZbJWQNbL2ZFoWuQc8BIJ5HDeatXJ+TZgUVodcBhVd0iRdFsVaFiMyGNIJ0uvlHm8oqng+QoBDPWw+AxZQsnHYqKXqZ4GawxwLoxhloZZSIunIzAqNgcWWXZeWSFjTYZ2AxwOF9oVmHYVTe3IkpUk5jUJNsKBupw9w5N6nA85wIsSDUBArYAFIAMoABqnPkHAsOzOScxwvqUOR2l3st5FZD8SsoQzB1OVr9iViA1BxOjfY-XDqI1lY4REIbRvmTTxVsOMRvOWkusPSWMVAA)):

```js
type Variant = "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary";

interface CommonProps {
  variant?: Variant;
  showChevron?: boolean;
  icon?: IconDefinition;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
  small?: boolean;
}

interface LinkOnlyProps extends React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  href: string;
}

interface ButtonOnlyProps
  extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}

export type LinkProps = CommonProps & LinkOnlyProps;
export type ButtonProps = CommonProps & ButtonOnlyProps;

export const Link = (props: LinkProps) => {
  const {
    children,
    showChevron,
    icon,
    fullWidth,
    variant,
    small,
    className,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  const { classes } = initButton(props);
  return (
    <a className={classes} {...rest}>
      <Content {...props} />
    </a>
  );
};

export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  const {
    children,
    showChevron,
    icon,
    fullWidth,
    variant,
    small,
    className,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  const { classes } = initButton(props);
  return (
    <button className={classes} {...rest}>
      <Content {...props} />
    </button>
  );
};
```

I've tried extracting the common logic for the `Link` and `Button` components into a single `Component`, however when I spread the `...rest` props I get TypeScript yelling at me. From the error, it seems because I haven't been able to account for the possibility of `<a>` props being spread on to a `<button>` element and vice-versa.

I wanted to keep `Link` and `Button` as separate components, rather than specifying the type as a prop, so that the intentionality of the developer is clear when the components are being implemented.

Is there any possibility of extracting that common logic into a central component that both `Link` and `Button` can simply act as wrappers for? For example:

```js
export const Link = (props: LinkProps) => {
  return <Component element="a" {...props} />;
}
export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  return <Component element="button" {...props} />;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471880/dynamic-tag-name-in-jsx-and-react

Comment: Reproducible example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play would help others to help you 

Comment: Great tip, @AlekseyL.—thank you! I've created a reproducible example as suggested and added it to the question content. ‍♂️

Comment: Looks like you can't get around type assertion (`as any`).. https://tsplay.dev/NnX6eW

Comment: I think you simplified your code for this question but it is confusing me because you are rendering the `<a>` or `<button>` twice and you are passing props like `showChevron` all the way down to the DOM.

Comment: You're right @LindaPaiste, I over simplified a few parts to keep the example short. the `...rest` spread should only pass either the Anchor or Button HTML Attribute props to the `<a>` or `<button>` respectively, while all props are sent to the `<Content>` component (which in turn also strips out my custom props before spreading to the DOM). Not sure if there is a cleaner way to achieve what I'm doing (probably!), but I haven't found it—yet! Appreciate your comments. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to work around the type assertion using `as any` when spreading the `rest` of my props:

```js
return (
  <Element className={classes} {...(rest as any)}>
    <Content {...props} />
  </Element>
);
```