# Passing custom tag name via props in React + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The solutions with string templates like

```
// var name must start with a capital letter
const CustomTag = `h${this.props.level}` as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;

<CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>
```

([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59685929/4818123), [source2](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-specify-dynamic-tag-name-in-react)) are invalid for TypeScript case. In below example

```js
import React from "react";
import type { ReactNode } from "react";


function OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel(
  properties: OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel.Properties
): JSX.Element {

  const RootElementTag: string = properties.rootElementTag ?? "div";

  return (
    <RootElementTag className="OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel">
      <span className="OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel-TextWithIncreasedLineHeight">
        { properties.children }
      </span>
    </RootElementTag>
  );
}


namespace OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel {
  export type Properties = Readonly<{
    rootElementTag?: string;
    children: ReactNode;
  }>;
}


export default OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel;
```

I got error

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.   
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

Hope it has clean the solution without `any` and `as`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `rootElementTag` to `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements` so that Typescript knows you are passing a valid tag

```js
namespace OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel {
    export type Properties = Readonly<{
        rootElementTag?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
        children: ReactNode;
    }>;
}
```

And in your component add the same type to `RootElementTag`

```
const RootElementTag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements = properties.rootElementTag ?? "div";
```